# I want to send multiple embedded images not as attachement

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to send an email using string, and the string having dynamic html image tag. I want to send these images as embedded not as an attachment.

```
// line breaks added to string for readability.
string html = 
    '<p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'>To,</p>
    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><br></p>
    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'>
    <img width="226" src="http://xxx/webserv/Attachment/Bulkemail/6/sqm/sqmbulkemail/images/1570287460400_26_10052019075743.png" class="fr-fic fr-dii"></p>
    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><br></p>
    <p style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.0pt;margin-left:0in;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'>Thanks,</p>'

foreach (var item in Text.ImgLink)
{
    oAttachment = oMail.AddAttachment(item);
}

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(Text.Text);
// var imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");

doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
    .Where(e =>
        {
            string src = e.GetAttributeValue("src", null) ?? "";
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(src) || src.StartsWith("data:image");
        })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x =>
        {
            string currentSrcValue = x.GetAttributeValue("src", null);
            string contentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 5);

            oAttachment.ContentID = contentId;

            x.SetAttributeValue("src", "cid:Img-" + contentId);
        });

string result = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

oMail.HtmlBody = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>" + result + " </body></html>";
```

Comment: You can use `AlternateView` and `LinkedResources` of `Net.MailMessage` class.

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: You can look at following example. http://aspalliance.com/1411_Using_LinkedResource_Class_for_Sending_HTML_Email_in_NET_20.6